# UseLATEX uses twice ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} in file names

Tags: cmake, latex

I am trying to use UseLATEX. It mostly works, but with the sample file below I receive messages `Could not find input file` then my ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
then ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} again, then the name of the file from InputFiles.
Of course, that file with the double-named directory cannot be found. What do I wrong?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)

PROJECT(Demo NONE)

set(MainFile "Demo.tex")
file(GLOB InputFiles
 *.tex src/*.tex dat/*.* lst/*.* 
 )
include(UseLATEX.cmake)

  ADD_LATEX_DOCUMENT( Demo.tex 
    INPUTS ${InputFiles} 
   )
```

Comment: 1) _UseLATEX_ is no standard CMake module, there is only _FindLATEX_, however, that find module doesn't provide a `add_latex_document` function/macro. 2) How do you invoke CMake? 3) What is the exact error message?

Comment: @Torbjörn 1) I did not state it is 3) It is given in the text: 'Could not find input file' plus twice ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} expanded plus file name. 2) I use the standard directory structure, except that I have directory build/build, and I invoke CMake from there with 'cmake ../..  -Wno-dev' (I need to make a local copy of some other file in build/, because it uses some files like '../../file.ext', and I want to keep the out-of-source build.

Comment: Update your question to contain all information. I was referring the exact _and_ complete error message.

Comment: In-source or out-of-source-build? In-source is not supported in UseLATEX.cmake.